# Writing type definition file for javascript library

Tags: typescript-typings

I am trying to write a type definition file (.d.ts) for the [disable-scroll npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/disable-scroll). I can see intellisense predictions in my code for the library I am using but when I try to run the app I am seeing

> Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript 2015 modules. Consider using 'import * as ns from "mod"', 'import {a} from "mod"', 'import d from "mod"', or another module format instead.

The type definition file

```
declare namespace disableScroll {
    class Options {
        readonly disableWheel: boolean;
        readonly disableScrollbar: boolean;
        readonly disableKeys: boolean;
        readonly scrollEventKeys: number[];
    }

    function on(element?: HTMLElement, options?: Options): void;
    function off(): void;
}

export = disableScroll;
```

The import

```
import disableScroll = require('../types/disable-scroll');
```

If I change the import to

```
import * as disableScroll from 'disable-scroll';
```

the code compiles and runs correctly but I lose my intellisense.

I have looked at lots of documentation online on how to write these files but I seem to be going round in circles. This is a relatively simple library and I'm sure that for someone with a better understanding of how this works it would be an easy task.

Any pointers on where I'm going wrong would be greatly appreciated.